# how to declare custom fee tax correctly

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, tax

I am trying to extend the following module: https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_CashOnDelivery (version 1.2.6).

That module adds a custom payment method (cash on delivery) and optionally adds a fee to the quote.

What I am trying to get is the correct tax applied to the fee. Totals are ok, but tax totals are not ok. I would expect a new row in the `sales_order_tax_item` table, but there isn't.

I suppose that it would be involved in the `Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax::processExtraTaxables()` method.

How can I declare the fee tax in a way that Magento would pick it up and add it to tax calculation?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it yourself? I have a similar problem.